# does jquery ui dialog support launching one dialog from (and on top of) another

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

[i have a jquery ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) where a user fills out a bunch of user inputs and then submits.  One of the fields is getting more complicated and has an advanced detail view so instead of showing all of the detail on the dialog, i want to show a button that will popup another jquery ui dialog on top of the first dialog with a mini set of user inputs.

is this supported in jquery ui dialog ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can..

i have a JSFiddle for this. check that out.

http://jsfiddle.net/79JWB/1/

Answer (score 1):

yes this can be done , call your

> new ui daliog

from your button in the form .

```
$('#buttonid').click(function(){

    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "ok": function() {
                //function
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    })

   });
```